# Side bar is not showing scrollbar in tailwind css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am making a WhatsApp clone using Tailwind CSS in ReactJS. I don't know why the side the contacts list is not showing the scrollbar instead it's getting overflowed which is resulting in scrollbar for the whole scree (as soon in the screenshot).
[image]

I can't understand why this is happening. Even I have tried to give a max height to the container div of the list but still no effect. Below is my code:

ChatListItem.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import List from "./List";

function ChatLIstItem() {
  const dummyChatList = [
    {
      name:"ABC",
      profilePic:'/avatars/1.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
    {
      name:"DEF",
      profilePic:'/avatars/2.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
    {
      name:"HIJ",
      profilePic:'/avatars/3.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
    {
      name:"KLM",
      profilePic:'/avatars/4.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
    {
      name:"NPO",
      profilePic:'/avatars/5.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
    {
      name:"RST",
      profilePic:'/avatars/6.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
    {
      name:"UVW",
      profilePic:'/avatars/7.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
    {
      name:"XYZ",
      profilePic:'/avatars/8.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
    {
      name:"XYZ2",
      profilePic:'/avatars/9.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
    {
      name:"XYZ2",
      profilePic:'/avatars/9.png',
      message:"Dummy message here!",
    },
  ]
  return <div className="bg-transparent max-h-screen overflow-auto">
    {dummyChatList.map((e,index)=>(
      <List key={index} profilePic={e.profilePic} name={e.name} message={e.message}/>
    ))}
  </div>;
}

export default ChatLIstItem;
```

List.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "../common/Avatar";

function List({ name, profilePic, message }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center hover:bg-input-background mt-1 p-4">
      <Avatar type={"lg"} src={profilePic} />
      <div className="flex flex-1 flex-col justify-between pl-4 gap-2">
        <span>{name}</span>
        <span className="text-secondary line-clamp-1 text-sm">{message}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default List;
```

May anyone knows what I am doing wrong here to stop this ugly overflow and get the horizontal scrollbar for the container that contains the list not for the whole screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

or

```css
* {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

NOTE: Please only apply this styling for the problematic container instead of everywhere (* is a wildcard selector in css)

Update: since you're working with tailwind, you probably need to add the box-border class or the overflow-x-hidden class to the problematic container. The above mentioned code is just to quickly diagnose.

Comment: Tried but doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Did you try it in the inspector-stylesheet of your browser (in your dev tools, click new style rule and then click the inspector-stylesheet:1 link)?
If you go: * {
        overflow: hidden !important;
}
I can almost guarantee the scrollbars will be gone everywhere.
Next step is to find the container where you need to apply this styling and use the tailwind equivalent instead.